# C# Vsts ReleaseManagement list approvals & approve

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a tool that automates the process of launching multiple builds pipelines and also the deployment pipelines.
I have succeded with the builds pipelines, but I have problems with the deployments.
I can get the deployments definitions and the release, but with this code **I only get the pending approvals** while I also want to get the already done approvals and approve/cancel
This tool wants to accelarate the devops process, since we are triggering builds and deployments from website (we approve and deploy each pipeline and we got a lot of)

```
var client = Connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient2>();
            var releaseDefs = await client.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync2(Config.Project);

        var ret = new List<ReleasePipelineModel>();
        foreach(var rd in releaseDefs)
        {
            var releases = await client.GetReleasesAsync2(
                Config.Project,
                definitionId: rd.Id, 
                top: 1,
                sourceBranchFilter: Constants.BranchBase + branch
            );
            var release = releases.FirstOrDefault();

            var stages = release != null ?
                await client.GetApprovalsAsync2(
                    Config.Project,
                    releaseIdsFilter: new[] { release.Id }
                )
                : null;

            ret.Add(new ReleasePipelineModel(rd)
            {
                LastRelease = release,
                Stage = stages?.FirstOrDefault()
            });
        }

        return ret.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();
```

I hope I was clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: use Deployment api

```
var deps = release != null ?
                await client.GetDeploymentsAsync(
                    Config.Project,
                    definitionId: rd.Id,
                    latestAttemptsOnly: true,
                    top: 1,
                    sourceBranch: Constants.BranchBase + branch)
                : null;
```

Comment: Glad you solve the problem and share the solution here. You can accept this answer thus other SO users who facing the same puzzle with you could directly know this is a work solution:-)